# Composition of Partial Isometries

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a complex Hilbert space and $S,T \in B(H)$ partial isometries. Then $S T$ is a partial isometrie, if and only if $T^*(\ker(S)) \subseteq \ker(ST)$.

Edit:
My attempts so far:

$\Rightarrow$: Let  $x \in \ker(S)$, then $||STT^*(x)||^2=<STT^*(x), STT^*(x)>=<PT^*(x),T^*(x)>$, where P is the orthogonal projection onto  $ker(ST)^\perp$. I've tried many different angles but this is where I always end up

Comment: this looks like homework. please show what you have tried, before expecting help.

Comment: It's not homework, I'm trying to understand this for my bachelor thesis, so I don't really have an idea what I might need to solve this. I added my attempts anyway

Answer (score 2):

Let's introduce the projections $P=S^*S$ (onto $(\ker S)^\perp$), and $Q=TT^*$ (onto $\operatorname{ran}T$). The condition of $ST$ being partial isometry is 
$ST=ST(ST)^*ST$
which simplifies to $ST=SQPT$. Rewrite this further as $S(I-QP)T=0$. Since $\ker S=\ker P$ and $\operatorname{ran} T = \operatorname{ran} Q$, the latter is equivalent to $P(I-QP)Q =0$. Thus, $ST$ is a partial isometry if and only if 
$$PQ = PQPQ \tag1$$

Next, look at the condition $T^*(\ker(S)) \subseteq \ker(ST)$. It is equivalent to $TT^*(\ker(S)) \subseteq \ker(S )$. Rewrite it as $Q(\ker P) \subseteq \ker P$. Express this as $PQ(I-P)=0$. So, the condition is equivalent to
$$PQ = PQP \tag2$$

Now it should be clear that (2) implies (1), and you need to work on the converse.

Comment: I've tried a little coming to the conclusion that $P(ran(Q)) \subseteq ran(Q)$ and thus  $P(\ker(Q)) \subseteq \ker(Q)$ leading to what I wanted. Is that it?